# Adding Spatial Index to CosmosDB using PythonAPI

Tags: python, geospatial, azure-cosmosdb, spatial

It seems that the 'Spatial' index type is missing from the definitions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/pydocumentdb.documents.indexkind?view=azure-python

How does one create a collection with a Spatial index programmatically via the Python API in CosmosDB then?

Simply typing the string "Spatial" or adding

{
    "kind": "Spatial",
    "dataType": "Point"
}

to the indices in the collection settings also does not seem to work. I'm not able to make spatial queries work on a Graph database populated via the DocumentAPI using Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't do this from non-.NET APIs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq